# Getting expanded frameset HTML, and a unique full path to an element in frame?

Tags: html, xpath, browser

Consider the example below, `test_load_frame.php` - it is a page built using `iframe` and framesets, and you can run it by running `php` CLI >= 5.4 as server:

```
php -S localhost:8080
```

... and you can then run the page in a browser as `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test_load_frame.php`. The output should look like this:

[image: firefox.png]

The thing is, once that page is loaded, Firefox "expands" the HTML with the frames content, so in Firefox Inspector I get full HTML like this: [expanded HTML in a GIST](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1ce52336a88f8fc1d17bf0326d38faea#file-test_load_frame_ffox-htm). The problem is, however, that I cannot just select that entire HTML tree in Firefox, and copy paste it elsewhere - so to do the tree in the Gist, I had to go and copy elements' outerHTML and paste it into the full tree file manually. So my first question is:

- Is there a tool, for Firefox or otherwise, that can copy or save the "expanded" HTML (which includes the HTML of all frames' content) in one go?

Then, I'd like to find a sort of a unique full path to the "This!" button, or `#thisbtn`. I know that I can use the Firebug extension for Firefox, to get a XPath to the element (right-click on the element in Firebug, and "Copy XPath"); however, for this particular example, it gives:

```
/html/body/h2/button
```

... which is only correct in the scope of the given frame, but not in the scope of the whole expanded document - roughly, I would call this a "relative" path; while what I would want, is an "absolute" path, expressed in terms of the root html document. So, in pseudocode, I would instead like to obtain something like (this I tried to derive manually from the "expanded" HTML):

```
/html/body/iframe[id="mainholder"]/html/frameset/frame[name="tl"]/html/body/h2/button[id="thisbtn"]
```

I have gathered from other questions on this site, that XPath cannot be used to provide such an "absolute" full path which crosses frame abstraction boundaries; thus the line above cannot be valid XPath, I guess.

But I'm OK with it: all I want is, for a page with a much more complicated frameset+iframe arrangement than this, to simply right-click on an element, and gain an awareness of how many frame levels there are between the particular element and the root -- then, it should get much easier to code frame switching and derive the proper XPath for, say, headless browser automation testing. So my second question is:

- Is there a tool, for Firefox or otherwise, that can show a "full"/"absolute" path to an element that includes any framesets/iframe's in-between?

**`test_load_frame.php`**

```php
<?php
if (array_key_exists("QUERY_STRING", $_SERVER)) {
  if ($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] == "getmain") {
    echo '<!doctype html>
  <html>
    <frameset rows="40%,60%">
    <frameset cols="50%,50%">
    <frame src="?gettl" name="tl">
    <frame src="?gettr" name="tr">
    </frameset>
    <frame src="?getbot" name="bottom">
    </frameset>
  </html>
  '; exit;
  }
  if ($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] == "gettl") {
    echo '<!doctype html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>TL  <button type="button" id="thisbtn">This!</button> </h2>
  </body>
  </html>
  '; exit;
  }
  if ($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] == "gettr") {
    echo '<!doctype html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <h3>TR</h3>
  </body>
  </html>
  '; exit;
  }
  if ($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] == "getbot") {
    echo '<!doctype html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <h4>BTM</h4>
  </body>
  </html>
  '; exit;
  }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <style type="text/css">
#mainholder {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  width: 70%; height: 150px;
}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>


<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>

   <iframe id="mainholder" src="?getmain"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

XPath 1.0 has no function to access secondary input documents, in XPath 2.0 or later you could use the `doc` function e.g. `doc(/html/body/iframe[id="mainholder"]/@src)`. However, usually XPath implementations work against XML documents, not HTML documents.

In a headless browser automation using Javascript and the DOM you would simply do `document.getElementById('mainholder').contentDocument` to access the document inside the `iframe` element.

Comment: Many thanks, @MartinHonnen, was not aware of the XPath 2.0 `doc`! The thing is, I'm already doing something similar to `document.getElementById('mainholder')...` in my actual case. However, it is easy knowing the iframe id in a simple case like this - the problem is when I have multiple framesets + iframes, and I don't know the page layout, I just have an element of interest; then in order to figure out the ID's, I have to spend 10s of minutes manually copy pasting HTML from Firefox - I'm pretty sure having a tool that can do "absolute path" (even if not proper XPath) would help.